# After Pushing View Controller Load a View From Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to have a different view controller appear as you change the device orientation and for that I am using a UINavigation Controller. When I call for the other view controller to be pushed `[self.navigationController pushViewController:graphView animated:YES];` It makes the transition but the screen is black and does not load this new controller "graphView"'s  view which is white with text.  I have done `graphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];` for the new controller but i do not have any storyboard connections made from the current view to the graph view nor do I have anything in my new view controller other than:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //[super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"loaded");
}
```

Is there an extra step since this is a new view controller to load the view from this view controller that i have on my storyboard?  Also the log does work meaning that is corrent.

Comment: This answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130981/push-view-controller-not-showing-elements-added-from-storyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing your 'graphView' like:

```
graphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];
```

You'll need to do this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
graphView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerId"];
```

**And make sure you set your ViewController's storyboard identifier in the storyboard:

1. Select your ViewController
2. Click the Identity inspector
3. Set the Storyboard ID ('YourViewControllerId' above)

Then, calling `pushViewController:animated:` as you were should present your ViewController appropriately.

Comment: Did you try this answer?